# how to us lib usb in c++

Tags: visual-c++

i want to communicate with usb port in c++. i know the libusb is a good way, but i can't use it. i have downloaded many libusb versions, for example  libusbx-1.0.12.tar,libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0,libusb-1.0.9.tar. but i have many problem with them. for example there is a header file in them i have made a project then add libusb.h to header files and use #include command in to the c++ empty project bud this command is unspacified. is ther any one here to help me, i want a step by step and complete instruction to use libusb.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/)

and read their [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/libusb-win32/wiki/Home/) very carefully.

Including a header file is not sufficient. You also need to link with the import library (which is a standard action you need to take when using 3th party libraries, and is unrelated to libusb)